# Linear Regression Homoskedasticity doubt

Tags: linear-regression, regression-analysis

I am trying to plot the Linear Regression between $(X,Y)$ where $X$ is the regressor/predictor and $Y$ is the output. The values are
np.random.seed(42)

```
x = np.random.rand(1, 5000)
y = np.random.rand(1, 5000)

# Find indices where x < y
fav = np.where(x < y)[1]
x = x[0, fav]
y = y[0, fav]
```

The Linear Regression of $Y$ on $X$ is given by the line $\mathbb{E}(Y|X=x)=(x+1)/2$

```
coefficient of determination: 0.2512995379407439
intercept: 0.4895868199625202
slope: [0.50666797]
```

When I want to check the assumptions of Linear regression I find that Residual $\epsilon$ is normally distributed by seeing the density.
[image] However when I plot the residual against the predicted value to check for presence of Homoskedasticity I get the following graph[image]

This graph means that there is Heteroskedasticity and an assumption is violated. But, what does this mean for our model. Should I just rely on this EDA or should I do some statistical tests like Pagan Test, Bartlett.

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider the data generation mechanism, $0<X<Y<1$, where $X$ and $Y$ are uniformly distributed.

$\bar{X}=\frac13,\bar{Y}=\frac23$.

We have $Y|X\sim Uniform(X,1)$ where $0<X<1$, hence we have $E(Y|X)=\frac{X+1}2$ and $$Var(Y|X)=\frac{(1-X)^2}{12}.$$

As we can see the variance is a function of $Y|X$ is a function of  $X$, here is a plot of the region along with its regression line plus two lines that are 1 standard deviation away.

[image]

It affects our inference, i.e. our confidence interval and hypothesis testing. Now that we diagnose the problem, what can we do?

Some possible solutions are presented in this [book chapter](https://www.sfu.ca/%7Edsignori/buec333/lecture%2018.pdf) and also a tutorial in R can be found in this [R reference](https://rpubs.com/cbw1243/gls).

If the residuals are uncorrelated, a common strategy is to use [weighted least square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_least_squares#:%7E:text=Weighted%20least%20squares%20(WLS)%2C,is%20incorporated%20into%20the%20regression.). Otherwise, we might resort to  [generalized least square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_least_squares) or more complex strategies.